# Freezing the time and date of a Virtual Machine in VMware Workstation

Tags: vmware, vmware-workstation, vmware-tools

Is there a way to freeze the time and date of a VM, so that it is not synchronized with the guest BIOS and/or the internet? I wish to avoid this as it changes the "clean state" of the VM (used for testing purposes).

To clarify: I don't want to set the time offset for a VM, I want to set the exact time that will be passed to the OS at boot time.

From there, is there a way to do this across a large number of VMs with version 16 or later?

**Code in python:**

```py
import datetime
import subprocess

VMWARE_VMRC_PATH = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware Remote Console\vmrc.exe"
VMWARE_VIX_PATH = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware VIX\vmrun.exe"

SET_VM_VARIABLE_COMMAND = r"setvmscript"
SCRIPT_DISABLE_SYNC_TIME = "var vm = FindServerConnection('" +
```